# Differentiate code running in production and staging slots

Tags: azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I have an Azure Function which has 2 slots: production and staging slots. Both slots have same values for all the config settings. For example, both slots send logs to the same log analytics workspace. Is there a way to differentiate the logs coming from staging and production slots? For example - add a prefix 'staging' for all the logs coming from staging slot?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Yes! You can differentiate the logs came from two different slots like Production and Staging Slot**.

I have created the .NET 6 Function App with 1 HTTP Trigger and 1 Timer Trigger published to both Production & Staging Deployment Slots.

**Production Slot Logs**:

[image]

**Staging Slot Function Logs**:

[image]

Here the Role name having 2 values:

- krishfuncnet6app01
- krishfuncnet6app01-staging

By default, the **App Insights SDK** set the ***cloud role name*** for you as the Azure ***App service Name*** which means the ***name*** of the Web App/Function App.

You can also set the custom Role Name to identify easily if you have multiple deployment slots, refer [here](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2020/02/05/setting-cloud-role-name-in-application-insights.aspx) for more information on a practical workaround of setting up the custom cloud role name using `TelemetryInitializer` class.